# Convert custom Excel sheet to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I have an XML file , which requires continuous changing for each environments and I would like to ease that by automating the process , I want to use an Excel to convert this to XML . I would like to write code in C#.

As it is different for different environments.

Below is part of XML file

```
<Mappings>
<Map>
  <SalesOrderNumber>11</SalesOrderNumber>
  <PurchaseOrderNumber>11</PurchaseOrderNumber>
  <ItemNumber>140007</ItemNumber>
  <Quantity>800</Quantity>
</Map>
<Map>
  <SalesOrderNumber>11</SalesOrderNumber>
  <PurchaseOrderNumber>12</PurchaseOrderNumber>
  <ItemNumber>140009</ItemNumber>
  <Quantity>200</Quantity>
</Map>
<Map>
  <SalesOrderNumber>11</SalesOrderNumber>
  <PurchaseOrderNumber>12</PurchaseOrderNumber>
  <ItemNumber>140010</ItemNumber>
  <Quantity>300</Quantity>
</Map>
<Map>
  <SalesOrderNumber>12</SalesOrderNumber>
  <PurchaseOrderNumber>12</PurchaseOrderNumber>
  <ItemNumber>140010</ItemNumber>
  <Quantity>400</Quantity>
</Map>
<Map>
  <SalesOrderNumber>12</SalesOrderNumber>
  <PurchaseOrderNumber>13</PurchaseOrderNumber>
  <ItemNumber>140006</ItemNumber>
  <Quantity>1300</Quantity>
</Map>
<Map>
  <SalesOrderNumber>13</SalesOrderNumber>
  <PurchaseOrderNumber>13</PurchaseOrderNumber>
  <ItemNumber>140006</ItemNumber>
  <Quantity>800</Quantity>
</Map>
```

I want send the files from excel so that I would get an XML in the above format .
I have multiple node, with same names as one can see. I have gone through many blogs , but nothing is helping me much , also I am unable to design my excel . I have these kind of multiple node around 25 to 30 with the sub nodes .

Any help on designing excel and converting these custom excel to XML programmatically using C# is appreciated

Comment: designing excel means what?

Comment: I think you want to do `xml → Excel`, not `Excel → xml` as title shown. right?

Comment: I wanted to actually convert excel to xml

Comment: I want to do this beacause , I have xml but my customer is not aware on how to modify it and may tamper the xml causing my code to fail.

Comment: I am looking for a design of excel ,where i can read the excel and convert to XML, I have gone through may sites but the code actually reads the Column header as the prime node , but I want it more easier way . So I am firstly unable to design the excel to match the need so that I can later convert to xml as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Here its easy to ***generate the Excel file***: you have numerous rows with 4 columns:

- `SalesOrderNumber`
- `PurchaseOrderNumber`
- `ItemNumber`
- `Quantity`

You must find a way in your `C#` to do 2 main things:

- load and translate the xml into a list of objects in your program
- output the content of the list of objects line by line

  - first in text mode, you may have enough with a `.csv`,
  - then you may have more luxury (not free) libraries to generate out-of-the-box Excel file if needed

Then to ***output XML from Excel***, this is basic ***`save as XML`*** procedure